# Plot With Blocks

Tags: r, plot

I have been searching for hours, but I can't find a function that does this.

How do I generate a plot like

[image: http://i.imgur.com/C2BXYPc.png]

Lets say I have an array `x1 = c(2,13,4)` and `y2=c(5,23,43)`. I want to create 3 blocks with height from 2-5,13-23...

How would I approach this problem? I'm hoping that I could be pointed in the right direction as to what built-in function to look at?

Comment: I am not aware of a function that can do that (although it's hard for me to see anything on the `png`), but you could write your own function using the `rect()`function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have not used your data because you say you are working with an array, but you gave us two vectors. Moreover, the data you showed us is overlapping. This means that if you chart three bars, you only see two.

Based on the little image you provided, you have three ranges you want to plot for each individual or date. Using times series, we usually see this to plot the min/max, the standard deviation and the current data.

The trick is to chart the series as layers. The first series is the one with the largest range (the beige band in this example). In the following example, I chart an empty plot first and I add three layers of rectangles, one for beige, one for gray and one for red.

```
#Create data.frame
n=100
df <-data.frame(1:n,runif(n)*10,60+runif(n)*10,25+runif(n)*10,40+runif(n)*10,35-runif(n)*10,35+runif(n)*10)
colnames(df) <-c("id","beige.min","beige.max","gray.min","gray.max","red.min","red.max")

#Create chart
plot(x=df$id,y=NULL,ylim=range(df[,-1]), type="n")  #blank chart, ylim is the range of the data
rect(df$id-0.5,df[,2],df$id+0.5,df[,3],col="beige", border=FALSE) #first layer
rect(df$id-0.5,df[,4],df$id+0.5,df[,5],col="gray", border=FALSE)  #second layer
rect(df$id-0.5,df[,6],df$id+0.5,df[,7],col="darkred", border=FALSE) #third layer
```

[image: layers]

Comment: I noticed that there appears to be white space on the left side and right side of the graph as the corner of the box does not immediately start at 0, is there a parameter that can get rid of this white space?

Comment: R automatically adds 4% blank space on each side of the chart. You can remove it on the x-axis with `xaxs="i"` in the plot command. Your command then becomes `plot(x=df$id,y=NULL,ylim=range(df[,-1]), type="n", xaxs="i", bty="l")` Note the `bty="l"` which removes the line on top and bottom. You will notice that the rectangles are now plotted over the left axis. You can redraw the axis by writing `axis(2)` after the last `rect` call.

Comment: Too late for an edit. I meant `bty="l"` removes the axis on top and to the right and keeps only an L-shaped axis.

Answer (score 2):

It's not entirely clear what you want based on the png, but based on what you've written:

```
x1 <-  c(2,13,4)
y2 <- c(5,23,43)
foo <- data.frame(id=1:3, x1, y2)

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data=foo) + geom_rect(aes(ymin=x1, ymax=y2, xmin=id-0.4, xmax=id+0.4))
```

[image]